# Preferred way to populate a byte buffer using BinaryPrimitives?

Tags: c#, .net

I am using `System.Buffers.Binary.BinaryPrimitives` to write values to a byte array in a precise way.
Without sample examples from MS I can see a few ways to do it and I am unsure if one is better than another. Principally, the need to create a lot of `Span<byte>` objects seems non-ideal?

Consider this simple example:

```
//writes these values in this order to a new 16-byte buffer
byte[] PopulateBuffer(int i1,int i2,Int16 s1,Int16 s2)
{
 var buffer = new byte[16]; //padded based on external protocol
 var span = new Span<byte>(buffer);
 BinaryPrimitives.WriteInt32LittleEndian(span.Slice(0,4),i1);
 BinaryPrimitives.WriteInt32LittleEndian(span.Slice(4,4),i2);
 BinaryPrimitives.WriteInt16LittleEndian(span.Slice(8,2),s1);
 BinaryPrimitives.WriteInt16LittleEndian(span.Slice(10,2),s2);
 return buffer;
}
```

I am instancing 5 `Span` objects here. Compared with the old-fashioned way of manually getting bytes by bit-shifting, that seems really messy but in reality is it much overhead? Is there a better way to use this class?

Comment: Please *don't* suggest other alternatives to `BinaryPrimitives`, this question is specifically about using that class. I asked about alternative approaches here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59774345/correct-way-to-convert-between-basic-types-and-raw-bytes/59786920#59786920

Comment: Even better than using `Span` internally is to let it percolate through the codebase (much like `async` / `await`), so you can have `void PopulateBuffer(Span<byte> buffer, ...)` and pass the `Span` externally (`Span<byte> buffer = stackalloc byte[16]`). This way, you cut down on the heap allocation, and allow sufficiently simple methods to be inlined, which in turn can cut down on range checks. Of course, whether it's viable to do so varies since it involves API changes.

Comment: @JeroenMostert indeed I had wondered about this. In the actual codebase I am still deciding whether to work on `List<byte>` rather than `byte[]` until the moment I actually need contiguous memory, to avoid reallocating and concatenating arrays. If possible, I agree this is a good plan

Comment: In most scenarios/protocols, it is possible to put a reasonable upper limit on the size of a packet, meaning you can work on a small number of fixed-size buffers (obtained with `ArrayPool`, for example), which also cuts down on allocation. This can be much more efficient than coughing up dynamic, resizing lists all the time. (Things like `Socket`, `NetworkStream` and related all allow for passing `Span`s, sliced arrays and/or an explicit `Length`, so you don't end up having to copy into an exact-sized array.)

Comment: @Mr.Boy Note that a `List<byte>` still has an array of contiguous memory underneath. It just has logic to create a new, bigger underlying array and copy everything over to it if needed

Comment: [This article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/system-io-pipelines-high-performance-io-in-net/) might be of interest, particularly the stuff around `BufferSegment` and `ReadOnlySequence`

Comment: I'd seen `ArraySegment` was supported - same basic principle I guess and I can see having a few big buffers which you use for your own super-simple memory 'allocation' using slicing would be fairly easy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TL;DR: from the results below, it looks like the `Span`-based approach is quite a bit *faster* than the alternative.

---

Note that `Span<T>` is a value type, and the JIT does quite a good job at seeing through it.

I created a simplified test:

```
using System;
using System.Buffers.Binary;
public class C
{
    byte[] PopulateBufferSpan(int i1, short s2)
    {
         var buffer = new byte[6];
         var span = new Span<byte>(buffer);
         BinaryPrimitives.WriteInt32LittleEndian(span.Slice(0,4), i1);
         BinaryPrimitives.WriteInt16LittleEndian(span.Slice(4,2), s2);
         return buffer;
    }

    byte[] PopulateBufferExplicit(int i1, short s2)
    {
        var buffer = new byte[6];
        buffer[0] = (byte)(i1 & 0xFF);
        buffer[1] = (byte)((i1 >> 8) & 0xFF);
        buffer[2] = (byte)((i1 >> 16) & 0xFF);
        buffer[3] = (byte)((i1 >> 24) & 0xFF);
        buffer[4] = (byte)(s2 & 0xFF);
        buffer[5] = (byte)((s2 >> 8) & 0xFF);
        return buffer;
    }
}
```

which JIT's to:

```
C.PopulateBufferSpan(Int32, Int16)
    L0000: push rdi
    L0001: push rsi
    L0002: sub rsp, 0x28
    L0006: mov esi, edx
    L0008: mov edi, r8d
    L000b: mov rcx, 0x7ffec35e2360
    L0015: mov edx, 0x6
    L001a: call 0x7fff230847e0
    L001f: lea rdx, [rax+0x10]
    L0023: mov ecx, 0x6
    L0028: mov r8d, ecx
    L002b: cmp r8, 0x4
    L002f: jb L0051
    L0031: mov r8, rdx
    L0034: mov [r8], esi
    L0037: mov ecx, ecx
    L0039: cmp rcx, 0x6
    L003d: jb L0057
    L003f: add rdx, 0x4
    L0043: movsx rcx, di
    L0047: mov [rdx], cx
    L004a: add rsp, 0x28
    L004e: pop rsi
    L004f: pop rdi
    L0050: ret
    L0051: call System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException()
    L0056: int3
    L0057: call System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException()
    L005c: int3

C.PopulateBufferExplicit(Int32, Int16)
    L0000: push rdi
    L0001: push rsi
    L0002: sub rsp, 0x28
    L0006: mov esi, edx
    L0008: mov edi, r8d
    L000b: mov rcx, 0x7ffec35e2360
    L0015: mov edx, 0x6
    L001a: call 0x7fff230847e0
    L001f: mov [rax+0x10], sil
    L0023: mov edx, esi
    L0025: sar edx, 0x8
    L0028: mov [rax+0x11], dl
    L002b: mov edx, esi
    L002d: sar edx, 0x10
    L0030: mov [rax+0x12], dl
    L0033: sar esi, 0x18
    L0036: mov [rax+0x13], sil
    L003a: movsx rdx, di
    L003e: mov [rax+0x14], dl
    L0041: sar edx, 0x8
    L0044: mov [rax+0x15], dl
    L0047: add rsp, 0x28
    L004b: pop rsi
    L004c: pop rdi
    L004d: ret
```

As you can see, there's very little difference between the complexity of the two, except that the version using `BinaryPrimitives` has a few range-checks (which are no bad thing).

Note that the JIT is multi-tiered these days, and I *think* SharpLab only shows the result of the first tier, so this might well be improved if it's on a hot path.

[SharpLab link](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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)

---

I also ran a benchmark using BenchmarkDotNet:

```
public class MyBenchmark
{
    private byte[] buffer = new byte[32];

    [Benchmark]
    public void PopulateBufferLESpan()
    {
        PopulateBufferLESpanImpl(1, 2, 3, 4);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void PopulateBufferLEExplicit()
    {
        PopulateBufferLEExplicitImpl(1, 2, 3, 4);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void PopulateBufferBESpan()
    {
        PopulateBufferBESpanImpl(1, 2, 3, 4);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void PopulateBufferBEExplicit()
    {
        PopulateBufferBEExplicitImpl(1, 2, 3, 4);
    }

    private void PopulateBufferLESpanImpl(int i1, int i2, short s1, short s2)
    {
        var span = new Span<byte>(buffer);
        BinaryPrimitives.WriteInt32LittleEndian(span.Slice(0, 4), i1);
        BinaryPrimitives.WriteInt32LittleEndian(span.Slice(4, 4), i2);
        BinaryPrimitives.WriteInt16LittleEndian(span.Slice(8, 2), s1);
        BinaryPrimitives.WriteInt16LittleEndian(span.Slice(10, 2), s2);
    }

    private void PopulateBufferLEExplicitImpl(int i1, int i2, short i3, short i4)
    {
        buffer[0] = (byte)(i1 & 0xFF);
        buffer[1] = (byte)((i1 >> 8) & 0xFF);
        buffer[2] = (byte)((i1 >> 16) & 0xFF);
        buffer[3] = (byte)((i1 >> 24) & 0xFF);
        buffer[4] = (byte)(i2 & 0xFF);
        buffer[5] = (byte)((i2 >> 8) & 0xFF);
        buffer[6] = (byte)((i2 >> 16) & 0xFF);
        buffer[7] = (byte)((i2 >> 24) & 0xFF);
        buffer[8] = (byte)(i3 & 0xFF);
        buffer[9] = (byte)((i3 >> 8) & 0xFF);
        buffer[10] = (byte)(i4 & 0xFF);
        buffer[11] = (byte)((i4 >> 8) & 0xFF);
    }

    private void PopulateBufferBESpanImpl(int i1, int i2, short s1, short s2)
    {
        var span = new Span<byte>(buffer);
        BinaryPrimitives.WriteInt32BigEndian(span.Slice(0, 4), i1);
        BinaryPrimitives.WriteInt32BigEndian(span.Slice(4, 4), i2);
        BinaryPrimitives.WriteInt16BigEndian(span.Slice(8, 2), s1);
        BinaryPrimitives.WriteInt16BigEndian(span.Slice(10, 2), s2);
    }

    private void PopulateBufferBEExplicitImpl(int i1, int i2, short i3, short i4)
    {
        buffer[0] = (byte)((i1 >> 24) & 0xFF);
        buffer[1] = (byte)((i1 >> 16) & 0xFF);
        buffer[2] = (byte)((i1 >> 8) & 0xFF);
        buffer[3] = (byte)(i1 & 0xFF);
        buffer[4] = (byte)((i2 >> 24) & 0xFF);
        buffer[5] = (byte)((i2 >> 16) & 0xFF);
        buffer[6] = (byte)((i2 >> 24) & 0xFF);
        buffer[7] = (byte)(i2 & 0xFF);
        buffer[8] = (byte)((i3 >> 8) & 0xFF);
        buffer[9] = (byte)(i3 & 0xFF);
        buffer[10] = (byte)((i4 >> 8) & 0xFF);
        buffer[11] = (byte)(i4 & 0xFF);
    }
```

With the results:

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.11.5, OS=Windows 10.0.16299.1565 (1709/FallCreatorsUpdate/Redstone3)
Intel Core i7-8650U CPU 1.90GHz (Kaby Lake R), 1 CPU, 8 logical and 4 physical cores
Frequency=2062501 Hz, Resolution=484.8482 ns, Timer=TSC
.NET Core SDK=3.0.100
  [Host]     : .NET Core 3.0.0 (CoreCLR 4.700.19.46205, CoreFX 4.700.19.46214), 64bit RyuJIT
  DefaultJob : .NET Core 3.0.0 (CoreCLR 4.700.19.46205, CoreFX 4.700.19.46214), 64bit RyuJIT

|                   Method |     Mean |     Error |    StdDev |   Median |
|------------------------- |---------:|----------:|----------:|---------:|
|     PopulateBufferLESpan | 1.772 ns | 0.0629 ns | 0.0558 ns | 1.745 ns |
| PopulateBufferLEExplicit | 3.698 ns | 0.0689 ns | 0.0576 ns | 3.688 ns |
|     PopulateBufferBESpan | 2.532 ns | 0.0791 ns | 0.0740 ns | 2.531 ns |
| PopulateBufferBEExplicit | 4.003 ns | 0.1106 ns | 0.2951 ns | 3.872 ns |
```

Showing, perhaps surprisingly, that the `Span`-based approach is significantly faster than doing bit manipulation. This is might be because x86 is little-endian, and `BinaryPrimitives` realises that it can blit the values straight into the array, without extracting and assigning each byte individually, but the BE variants also show a fairly significant difference.

Comment: The compiler succeeds in eliding the range checks if the `Span` written to is a `stackalloc`, but not for the heap-based local array. Some room for improvement there still, apparently.

Comment: What a great answer, thankyou. There are quite a _lot_ of remarks around the allowed use of `Span` and I suppose these limitations allow 'objects' to be optimised almost entirely away leaving just the operations performed?

Comment: @JeroenMostert It might be that the second JIT tier gets rid of those? I'm not knowledgeable enough to check, though.

Comment: @Mr.Boy What "allowed use of span" are you referring to? The fact that it's a `ref struct` type? I think the optimisations here are "just" the JIT inlining small methods, although I could be wrong: it could have special knowledge of `Span<T>`

Comment: @canton7 The jit has a little bit of special knowledge about `Span<T>`: it knows exactly what the indexer does. The jit also has a little bit of special knowledge about the underlying `ByReference<T>`. I'll have to look into those missing bounds checks at some point...

Answer (score 1):

`Span`s are a `ref struct` type. Creating spans will create very concise objects with references to the original array and the begin to end range positions you declared.

`Span`, `ReadOnlySpan` and `Memory` were introduced specifically for better performance working with sequences, especially memory/byte sequences.

You can think of Spans as array sections pointers. Creating, copying, and accessing this pointer structure is comparatively cheap. When operating on it you still operate on the original, underlying array. (No additional array instances are used.)

You mention bit shifting. I assume you mean that as an alternative to `BinaryPrimitives.WriteInt32LittleEndian`.

If instead of the *WriteInt32* method you were to manually extract the four bytes, and set them into the array by index, you invest multiple bit operations and potentially break linear vector operations that could be CPU-optimized through SIMD instructions, branch predictions, and caching. So a bit operating approach is not necessarily "cheap" either.

It can be hard to predict which approach is more performant. To be sure about performance differences you would have to test your use case specifically.

In general, using Span is not an expensive operation, and using the methods provided by the standard library is preferable [over manually replicating their behavior].